# UITextfield how to make border radius and keep the border shadow also radius

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have text files and I want to change the radius of it, the text field took the radius correctly but the border looks like a cut in it.

How I can make the border also to be radius? 
see the below image

[image]

Comment: There might be a clash in total frame of the textfield its radius and padding..try setting a bigger frame or reduce radius

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use this code. It's working well for me:

```
UITextField* txtfield = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 32)];
[txtfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
txtfield.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
txtfield.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
txtfield.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
txtfield.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview:txtfield];
```

Set the **background in your view**, and set the **borderColor to clearColor**.